How to auto-size text font based on set cell dimensions of a merged cell group and wrapped text?
If I have a Merge&Centered set of cells with WrapText active, how can I autofit the font size to fit with these conditions?
I've tried .ShrinkToFit, but .WrapText circumvents it.
Likewise, if I turn .WrapText off, .ShrinkToFit works, but then cycling .WrapText back on resets it to its original font size.
Any ideas? Is it possible?
This is a follow-up question to this question from nigh 13 years ago...
Given a fixed cel width, can I change the fontsize so that the text will fit inside the cell?

"but then cycling .WrapText back on resets it to its original font size." - could you store the font size, then turn .WrapText back on and then re-apply the stored font size?

Thing is, it autosizes to an extremely small size that isn't even legible. Much smaller than what would be considered necessary for the length of text inside.

@CLR I do appreciate the innovative idea though!
